# Reading SVN (Subclipse) rev number from java code

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subclipse, javahl

I'd like to be able to read the current svn revision number (I'm using Subclipse) from my Java Code to output it with the rest of the things I need in my regression tests written using JUnit 4.

I googled a lot without any luck (some info pointing to javahl.jar, but I wasn't able to figure out anything useful for my case), I also tried to figure out by myself but no luck again.

Environment:

- Eclipse Version: 3.6.2, Build id: M20110210-1200
- Windows 7 32-bit
- Subclipse 1.6.18 (JavaHL 1.6.17)

If possible I'd like to avoid to read .snv files directly and reach a "clean" solution because I have to leave this code to other people.

Thanks in advance,
Alessandro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the questions seems still open even if I solved the problem, I post here the code for clarity even if it was already inserted into a commet:

```
import org.tigris.subversion.javahl.*;
[...]

SVNClient svnClient = new SVNClient();
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Status [] status = svnClient.status("absolutepathOfTheProject", true, false, true);

for(Status stat : status)
revNumber = (revNumber < stat.getRevisionNumber()) ? stat.getRevisionNumber() : revNumber;
```

Please note that this stub uses some deprecated methods, it is of course possible to replace them with other methods, but this is to be intended as a guideline for solving the original problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library "svnkit" - svnkit.com

On wikipage there are many examples and one of them is "For getting info on Working Copy items"

http://wiki.svnkit.com/Managing_A_Working_Copy

Also example how to use it you can find in source code of project 
http://code.google.com/p/svntask/

Answer (score 1):

I would look into **SVNKit**, particularly the [`SVNWCClient#doInfo()`](http://svnkit.com/javadoc/org/tmatesoft/svn/core/wc/SVNWCClient.html#doInfo%28java.io.File,%20org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNRevision%29) method.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

In the meanwhile I managed to get it working in this way (I know that I should avoid the deprecated method but I'm really in a hurry, for now it will be ok):

`import org.tigris.subversion.javahl.*;
[...]

SVNClient svnClient = new SVNClient();
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
Status [] status = svnClient.status("absolutepathOfTheProject", true, false, true);

for(Status stat : status)
revNumber = (revNumber < stat.getRevisionNumber()) ? stat.getRevisionNumber() : revNumber;`